# Exposing Spring Boot metrics to influxDB for grafana visualization

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, influxdb, grafana

I have a Spring Boot application running on Cloud Foundry that exposes metrics and health info via the /metrics & /health endpoints respectively. I'd like to post these metrics as a continuous stream to an influxDB user provided service for visualization on a grafana dashboard. I am looking for any resources that explain how the dataflow would work and would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you specifically need to import data into InfluxDB for some reason (other that that it's awesome)? I am asking because there are resources on getting the metrics data into Graphite (and therefor storing it in Whisper db). You could then easily point grafana to the graphite server and visualize the data. Adding to InfluxDB could most definitely be done, but I am guessing it would take a lot of manual coding (I am not aware of any ready-made solution)

Comment: Thanks - yes, I only have the influxDB (with Grafana) binding in my landscape

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know there is no ready made solution.
However what you can do is implement a custom [Exporter](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.5.x/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/export/Exporter.html) for InfluxDB.

The details of how to do this in Spring Boot can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metric-writers).
In essence what you need to implement is an exporter that converts the Spring Boot metrics data to InfluxDB's [line protocol](https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/write_protocols/line.html)

Another possible solution would be to get the [Spring Boot metrics into Dropwizard metrics](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-dropwizard-metrics) and then use [this](https://github.com/davidB/metrics-influxdb) external library for reporting the Dropwizard metrics into InfluxDB (or use the [master](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/tree/master) branch of dropwizard metrics which already an InfluxDB backend).

Finally, if you want to forgo InfluxDB and instead save the data into Graphite's storage (Whisper database), you should check out [this](http://kielczewski.eu/2015/01/application-metrics-with-spring-boot-actuator/) or [this](https://objectpartners.com/2015/05/07/intelligent-microservice-metrics-with-spring-boot-and-statsd/). Once the data is in Graphite, Grafana can easily visualize it as is shown [here](http://docs.grafana.org/datasources/graphite/)

Comment: Many thanks @geoand. I've tried your second suggestion and got stuck with the https://github.com/davidB/metrics-influxdb external library because it supports influxDB 0.8x not 0.9x. While I await a fix for this library, could you please share the resources you mentioned for reporting data into Graphite API (your initial suggestion)?

Comment: You're welcome! Check me update answer for the extra suggestions

Comment: Thanks again. However, only counter.* and gauge.* metrics from the /metrics endpoint of my Spring Boot application are showing up in grafana (via graphite). Is there a way to expose the entire set of metrics including jvm parameters, cpu util etc. as a scheduled job? I have come across some links but everyone seems to have their own way (and use other libraries) to do this. What would be the recommended way forward?

Comment: @citizenBane Glad to here it's working (at least partly). I can't say that I have a ready solution off of the top of my head for your issue. It seems like you'll have to integrate of the solution you have found with your existing implementation

Comment: The Link to Exporter navigates to 404 Not Found Page.

Comment: @NikolayChernov Thanks for reporting! Fixed

Answer (score 3):

It might be possible to write a [telegraf](https://github.com/influxdb/telegraf) plugin to emit the metrics to InfluxDB. Otherwise, the [influxdb-java](https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-java) library might simplify emitting the metrics directly from Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2):

Telegraf meets your requirements. It pulls data from jolokia and save to InfluxDB.

All you need to do is enable actuator and jolokia for SpringbootApplication, it is easy to add dependency to your maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
        <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

After this you need configure telegraf to connect your web server and influxDB, here is an example config:

```
[tags]
dc = "local-1"

[agent]
interval = "10s"

[[inputs.jolokia]]
context = "/jolokia"

[[inputs.jolokia.servers]]
name = "catalog"
host = "{web server ip address}"
port = "{web server port}"

[[inputs.jolokia.metrics]]
name = "metrics"
mbean  = "org.springframework.boot:name=metricsEndpoint,type=Endpoint"
attribute = "Data"

[outputs]
[outputs.influxdb]
url = "{http://influxdb:port}"
database = "telegraf"
precision = "s"
```

Make sure network of upper configuration is available, then you will get data in you influxDB.

Configure grafana to display the data stored in influxDB:

1. Add a influxDB type datasource
2. Create a new Dashboard and Graph panel.
3. Configure Graph panel and choose which filed you want to display in Metrics setting.

You will see the data on the panel.

Answer (score 1):

There are two implementations possible with influxdb :-

a) For influxdb version <= 0.8.8 you can use metrics-influxdb jar to put your app time series data on running influxdb server.

b) For influxdb version > 0.8.8 you can use influxdb-java jar to put your app time series data on running influxdb server.

Now about how to install & manage influxdb with grafana you can follow following useful links :-
http://www.philipotoole.com/influxdb-and-grafana-howto/ 
http://blog.sflow.com/2014/12/influxdb-and-grafana.html 
https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/creating-a-grafana-and-influxdb-docker-container/ 
https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.6/ui/grafana.html

Answer (score 1):

InfluxDB (unlike Prometheus) is a push based system. It cannot poll a HTTP endpoint to collect metrics. Your application needs to contiguously/periodically push data into InfuxDB instance.

To push application into InfluxB, others have suggested libraries like influxdb-java, [metrics-influxdb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32691143/3679857), etc.

There is one more (and much better IMO) solution.

You can have a look at a new library, developed by Spring team, called [micrometer](https://micrometer.io/docs).

Micrometer is a metrics collection library with support for a huge number of TSDBs (Influx being one of them). It was first introduced in Spring 2, and has been since back-ported to Spring 1.3+.

Micrometer publishes [all of default actuator metrics](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector#what-do-i-get-out-of-the-box) out of the box. It is super-easy to [get started with](https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/influx). You can read about all the capabilities [here](https://micrometer.io/docs).